# What determines the amount of condition damage from conditions applied by sigils and traits?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Some sigils can inflict conditions. One example is the sigil of earth. It has a certain percent chance of inflicting bleeding when you critically strike.

Trait benefits can also inflict conditions. One example of this is the Guardian's Shatter Aegis trait. It inflicts burning around the Guardian if aegis is popped.

Unlike the weapon and slot skills which explicitly states the amount of total damage the conditions deal of the stated time, the description for the sigil and trait conditions do not say how much total damage is dealt.

How is this damage determined? I assume condition damage also increase the damage of these conditions?

Comment: My guess would be each condition has a default amount and having +condition damage gear will increase that base. I don't think condition damage scales with say power or anything.

Comment: @Emerica, there has to be some sort of scaling though. If there really is just a flat amount of dmg from the conditions then it would be too overpowered early game.

Comment: Or inversly extremely under powered late game haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damage calculated varies from condition to condition.

[Bleeding Formula:](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bleeding)

> 2.5 + 0.5 * Level + 0.05 * Condition Damage per stack per second

[Poison Formula:](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Poison)

> Level + 0.1 * Condition Damage per second

[Burning Formula:](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Burning)

> 4.1 * Level + 0.25 * Condition Damage per second

[Confusion Damage:](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Confusion)

> 25 + 0.5 * Level + 0.075 * Condition Damage per stack per skill use

Comment: Your assertion is, "All conditions are the same", yes? All bleeds applied by the same character will deal X damage, regardless of source?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: I believe so, yes. I originally thought it varied, but I was experimenting with the Engineer and it looks like the skill itself has no impact.